# Why does the Parse.com login view hide the Facebook login button?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've set up the Parse Login in my iOS app, but I'm trying to turn on some features.  When I do that, the Facebook login button disappears.  The lines of code that seem to do this are below.  If I comment out these 2 lines, everything works fine.  I'm not sure why.

`[logInViewController setEmailAsUsername:true];
[logInViewController.logInView.logo setHidden:YES];`

this is code for the fields that I've setup in the view:

`[logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword|PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton|PFLogInFieldsDismissButton|PFLogInFieldsFacebook|PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten];`

I'm not subclassing the view (which I do realize will give me more customization options and control, but I'm just throwing this in just to set it up)  I'm using Parse-library 1.6.1.  Like I said, without those 2 lines, everything works fine. Has anyone else experienced this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: subclass it your worries will go away

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Subham93 I subclassed the view and created my own view.  That seemed to do the trick for me.  It wasn't as hard as I thought it was going to be.